# Hi, I'm trying to create a list with multiples arrays that i get from indexing a huge array that contains them

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have my original array that has 85 arrays, and i can access to them like this

```
da1[34]
```

The problem is that I have a list (aa) where I have the specific index for the arrays I need. I want to make a loop to append all that arrays in a new list, so i used this code

```
aa=[45,76,18,34]
for i in aa:
    orden=[]
    orden.append(da1[i])
```

But I only get an array, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
What I hope is to get the same number of arrays as the number of indexes that I have in aa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the list outside the loop, like this:

```
aa=[45,76,18,34]
orden=[]
for i in aa:
    orden.append(da1[i])
```

The reason is you are creating the list every time you iterate in the for. So at the end you end up only with the last element in the list.